# Nvidia driver install

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I tried blacklisting and everything I could find on the internet used with root and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> with no solution :

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Mon Jun 17 08:35:25 2013
installer version: 319.23

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 319.23.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  
   Continue installation anyway? (Answer: Yes)

ERROR: The Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system.  This driver is 
incompatible with the NVIDIA driver, and must be disabled before proceeding.  Please 
consult the NVIDIA driver README and your Linux distribution's documentation for 
details on how to correctly disable the Nouveau kernel driver.

WARNING: One or more modprobe configuration files to disable Nouveau are already 
present at: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf.  Please be sure 
you have rebooted your system since these files were written.  If you have rebooted, 
then Nouveau may be enabled for other reasons, such as being included in the system 
initial ramdisk or in your X configuration file.  Please consult the NVIDIA driver 
README and your Linux distribution's documentation for details on how to correctly 
disable the Nouveau kernel driver.

ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' 
for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README 
available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Comment: Are you killing your graphic interface before? Try `crt + alt + f1`, login, and type `sudo lightdm stop` before running the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand what your problem is but you can find the nvidia driver for Ubuntu in the Software and updates app (look in the dash) under the additional drivers tab.
[image]

This is the best way to install, also version 3.10 is recommended as it is most stable.

Comment: actually idont have additional drivers tab

Comment: Try using this PPA in terminal type - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates - then - sudo apt-get update - and finally - sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates

Answer (score 0):

I have the nvidia gtx 650 and I know some nvidia cards are supported yet by the open source drivers.   When I instlaled my nvidia card 6 months ago I made some notes and maybe they will help you as well...

Before installing any video drivers from the following MAKE SURE I have installed `ppa-purge`

- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-ppa-purge-with-multi-arch.html

Then from xorg-edgers (bleading edge/latest NVIDIA support in Ubuntu):
NOTE: substitute for quantal whatever version of Ubuntu you are using

- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers?dist=quantal

To use latest NVIDIA drivers I installed this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

and installed these packages from it to support the GTX 650 card with the Nvidia 310 drivers etc:

```
sudo apt-fast install nvidia-settings-310 nvidia-310
```

so remove these BEFORE any Distro Upgrades with Ubuntu or I'll have a **broken** system
by doing this command:

```
sudo ppa-purge nvidia-settings-310 nvidia-310
```

NOTE by THEM:

> **IMPORTANT NOTICE** - If you are upgrading from one release to another and are using this PPA, be sure to install ppa-purge and use it to downgrade all of this PPA's packages before the upgrade or you will have a broken system.