# Ubuntu release upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 fails - log-in fails

Tags: unity, 14.04, nvidia, compiz, lightdm

## Upgrading Ubuntu

To upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10. to 14.04. I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade`. The first attempt failed and I found the following message in the error log:

```
/var/log/dist-upgrade/20140724-1529/main.log:

ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' is marked 
for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
```

After I successfully uninstalled the package I re-ran the upgrade.

## The initial problem

I restarted the computer and then it stops booting with the following screen output:

```
* Starting nginx nginx
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
 * Restoring resolver state
 * Starting web server apache2
 *
```

## Trying to start the UI

From the console I tried to launch the UI running: `sudo service lightdm start` which fails with the message:

> Job failed to start

Looking into `/var/log/lightdm/` I found the following errors:

```
x-0-greeter.log:

WARNING: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 \
  /2.10.0/loaders.cache': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
This likely means that your installation is broken
Try running the command
gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache \
  to make thinks work again for the time being
WARNING: Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/entry.png':
  Format der Bilddatei unbekannt
WARNING: Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/ \
  entry-disabled.png': Format der Bilddatei unbekannt
/usr/sbin/unity-greeter: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: 
  undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale
** (gnome-settings-daemon:2614): WARNING **: Could not open X display
```

..

```
x-0.log:

Loading extension GLX
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could 
  not find module by name='nvidia_311'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_331': Function not implemented
error setting MTRR (base = 0xf3000000, size = 0x00e00000, type = 1) Invalid argument (22)
```

## Graphics driver

Some weeks ago I switched to another graphics driver as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/309251/18533).
As suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217923&p=13008050#post13008050) I downloaded the current NVidia driver for my graphics card from their website and run the following and run:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.79.run
```

However, the setup stops with the following message:

> The distribution-provides pre-install script failed! Continue installation anyway? [YES] [NO]

I have chose `NO` for now.

## Running apt-get

Next I decided to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

In the middle of something it stopped with the following message:

```
Setting up nvidia-331 (331.38-0ubuntu7) ...

Configuration file '/etc/init/nvidia-persistenced.conf'
 ==> Deleted (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ? Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** nvidia-persistenced,conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I chosen `Y` since I wasn't lucky with what was installed as you might guess..

## Partial success

Rebooting the system the UI launched!
However, when I enter my password to the log-in field **nothing happens**. Also the log-in field looks somewhat odd - the user name is barely readable - as if the background graphic is missing (see screen foto).

[image: Ubuntu log-in mask]

Then I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session` and restarted one again.
Now I can log-in.

The problem which remains: the **window manager seems to be broken**. I cannot see the Unity dash, window menu bars, ...

[image: Ubuntu desktop without Unity]

## Graphics driver nightmare second part

Meanwhile, I decided to install the driver mentioned before regardless of the warnings:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.79.run
```

Now, the system boots: I can see the shell login prompt for a second but no UI and the screen stays black. When I press the power button the system shuts down (I can see the routines). I can **no longer access the shell** via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Seems as if I messed it up :(

Recovered to the previous state (no menu bars) by adding the attribute `text` to the [kernel parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) as [suggested by  bain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504043/ubuntu-release-upgrade-from-13-10-to-14-04-fails-log-in-fails#comment678477_504043).

## Errors or warnings in /var/log/syslog

**[/var/log/syslog:](http://pastebin.com/NV4NGJQX)**

```
Jul 30 09:28:23 E6500 kernel: [  186.883606] traps: compiz[2666] trap int3 ip:7f97c4279c13 sp:7fff48a43bf0 error:0
Jul 30 09:28:25 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 5
Jul 30 09:28:25 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jul 30 09:28:25 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Jul 30 09:28:26 E6500 kernel: [  189.550661] traps: compiz[3059] trap int3 ip:7fb39f46ec13 sp:7fff38ee5170 error:0
Jul 30 09:28:26 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
Jul 30 09:28:26 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal 5
Jul 30 09:28:26 E6500 gnome-session[2560]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Crashes after installing NVIDIA-331 or NVIDIA-CURRENT driver (GTX 765M)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/479504/ubuntu-14-04-crashes-after-installing-nvidia-331-or-nvidia-current-driver-gtx-7)

Comment: @bain Still the menu bars are hidden.

Comment: Does it work if you create a guest account and log in to that?

Comment: @bain Cannot tell. See my last update: I made it even worse now.

Comment: Boot with `text` in the kernel parameters, then login and `sudo apt-get purge --remove nvidia*` and then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Comment: @bain Did that now - thanks for the recovery hint. Same problems with a newly created user account: no UI such as the Unity dash, window menu bars, ...

Comment: Do you see any errors in /var/log/syslog? Can you try booting from the 14.04.1 ISO image and test if the desktop works? If it does, then I would suggest a fresh install is the quickest way to fix this. If it does not, then report it as a bug on Launchpad.

Comment: @bain Here is the [syslog](http://pastebin.com/NV4NGJQX) of this morning boot. Nothing critical as far as I can see. - What part of the system is responsible for rendering the unity dash, menu bars, ...?

Comment: syslog shows compiz crashing at the end - there is a bug report for that [#1336467 compiz trap int3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1336467) but the reporter says it was fixed by an update. Make sure you are up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)

Comment: Some people report that doing `cd ~ && rm -rf .gconf .gnome2 .local .config` fixed a similar trap int3 error from compiz.

Comment: @bain Nice! It worked after `dist-upgrade`. Would you please post a "full" answer summarizing the steps we took - and I will be more than happy to grant you the answer flag. (I do not believe the profile settings work since the error is visible at the log-in screen already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug ([#1336467 compiz trap int3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1336467)) that was fixed in an update.

(If you can not access a virtual terminal with ctrl-alt-f1, then boot with `text` in the kernel parameters and login to the text terminal)

In a terminal do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove nvidia*
sudo apt-get update && sudo dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: I just did `sudo apt-get update && sudo dist-upgrade && sudo reboot` which was good enough to fix the problem. At the moment NVIDIA 331.38 is active.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the propriatary NVIDIA driver.

When you are at the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.

Then execute the following command:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get -y autoremove sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-331 && sudo apt-get shutdown -r now`

This will remove everything from NVIDIA and install the latest NVIDIA driver that comes from Ubuntu.

Comment: What might also help is doing (inside tty) a dist-upgrade: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade